# How to preserve image transparency when converting to HSV in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, transparency, hsv

So I'm attempting to convert my image from RGB to HSV so I can manipulate the hue of the image. I managed to figure out how to change the hue using numpy and pillow, but every time I use image.convert(), on a transparent image, it eliminates the transparency and affects the image quality. How can I preserve the image's transparency when converting it to HSV and back again?

My code:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("flame.png")
new_img = img.convert("HSV")
new_img.show()
```

[image: flame.png]
[image: after conversion]

---

UPDATE:

So I attempted to preserve the alpha channel by creating and alpha mask and applying it on the converted image. Here's the modified code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2

alpha = cv2.imread("traits/Background/background.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(alpha[:, :, 3], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
channel = Image.fromarray(mask)

img = Image.open("traits/Background/background.png")
new_img = img.convert("HSV")
new_img = new_img.convert("RGBA")
new_img.putalpha(channel)
new_img.show()
```

This is the result:

[image: result]

It has some transparency now but still looks terrible. Still doesn't preserve the original transparency.

How would you go about extracting and storing the alpha channel in a way that preserves the original quality?

Comment: You will need to extract the alpha channel and store it separately. PIL [does not have an "HSVa" mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
alpha = im.getchannel('A')
```

to grab the alpha channel. Then do your processing and afterwards restore the alpha channel:

```
im.putalpha(alpha)
```

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick!

Not sure why I couldn't find the image.getchannel() method. I Googled all over and couldn't find anything like that.

Thanks!